# pi frequently freezes up on disk reads - is flash drive broken?

Tags: sd-card, fsck

My pi freezes up when trying to do basic operations like `ls`, opening `vi`, evening `cat` on arbitrary files.

It's slightly sporadic in that I can open a new terminal and reconnect, reboot, but the problem is always there if I try to do anything even marginally substantial.

I've heard of people having SD cards fail in their pi, and I specifially bought a solid state flash usb drive to avoid this ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B08GY3Z4JR/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08GY3Z4JR))

So is this indicative that the flash drive is failing?

Is there a safe way to run fsck with only remote access?

Comment: for clarification, the freezing only happens on the USB Flash drive and not eh SD card, correct?

Comment: Correct. The USB flash drive is my only drive on the pi.

Answer (score 2):

Freezes during disk access are a typical symptom of an actual disk failure, where re-reading an arbitrary sector is very long. I never encountered this with flash media, but a high number of failing sectors might theoretically cause this on a flash media as well.

One way to limit the freezing is to set timeouts to a smaller value:

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/device/timeout
echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/device/eh_timeout
```

Running `fsck` via SSH requires two tricks. First, you don't want to terminate the check if SSH disconnects. If you run it non-interactively, you can use `nohup` which will close STDIN and redirect STDOUT to a file. If you want to decide what to do with each error, you can use a terminal multiplexer, such as `screen`.

The second trick is needed when you need to check the root partition. If you boot from your flash drive, you need to run `fsck` at boot time before the partition is mounted as read/write. You can try one of the following commands to do this :

```
touch /forcefsck
tune2fs -c 1 /dev/sdxy
```

Comment: Thanks, Dmitry. If fsck fails or is unable to fix the problem, will it continue booting or will the pi be stuck trying to run fsck every time it is booted?

Comment: Nevermind - I see that's what the `-c 1` does.

Comment: @User7391 A very valid concern indeed. You might want to try the `/forcefsck` approach first.